# Find a file on a remote computer via powershell

Tags: powershell

Exist the posibility to check if a file exist on a remote server or a list of servers via powershell without defining the path where the file is placed? For example a want to check if the file "test.txt" exist on server A but i don't know the path where is placed.

Comment: Yes. That's easily possible.  ;-)

Comment: could you please help me with a code example :D

Comment: i used this code "'Get-Childitem –Path C:\ -Include *log4j* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'" but  the partition should be defined

Comment: I think you misunderstood something about this vulneravbility. It's pretty unlikely that you find files with the name *log4j* even if you use vulnerable software. You may find helpfull information here [https://github.com/NCSC-NL/log4shell](https://github.com/NCSC-NL/log4shell)

Comment: I have find out an answer for ur deleted question while posting deleted. –